# Python-reverse=True reversing issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
def last_name(str):
    return str.split()[1]

names = ["Isaac Newton", "Fred Newton", "Niels Bohr"]
print("s:", sorted(names, key=last_name))
print("s:", sorted(names, key=last_name, reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
s: ['Niels Bohr', 'Isaac Newton', 'Fred Newton']
s: ['Isaac Newton', 'Fred Newton', 'Niels Bohr']
```

When I use `reverse=True` , shouldn't it be like this: `['Fred Newton','Isaac Newton', 'Niels Bohr']`?

Comment: Why should it be?

Comment: Why? You're sorting on last_name.. Newton = Newton, the order of Fred vs. Isaac is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's sorting algorithm is *stable*. If two values have the same `key(value)` results, then their relative order is kept the same. Reversing only applies to `key(value)` results that *differ*.

Because `key('Isaac Newton')` and `key('Fred Newton')` both produces `'Newton'`, these two strings are left in their original relative order. The `reverse=True` flag only influences if `'Bohr'` is sorted before or after `'Newton'`.

If you need their relative order reversed, sort *forwards*, and then reverse the resulting list.